# How can I stop DevForce from swallowing exceptions in the EntityManager.EntityChanged event

Tags: c#, exception, devforce

This is yet another continuation of a thread from the DevForce forums [here](http://www.ideablade.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=2634&title=exceptions-and-entitymanagerentitychaged-event).  The problem is that DevForce will silently swallow any exception that gets thrown by the EntityManager.EntityChanged event if the change was triggered by a query or import.  The relevant code looks like this:

```
internal virtual void OnEntityChanged(EntityChangedEventArgs args)
{
    EventHandler<EntityChangedEventArgs> entityChanged = this.EntityChanged;
    if (entityChanged == null) return;
    try
    {
        entityChanged(this, args);
    }
    catch
    {
        if (args.Action != EntityAction.AddOnQuery && args.Action != EntityAction.AddOnImport)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the forum thread, the behavior of this method has changed a bit overtime.  Less things are swallowed now than they were when I first complained about this.  But for our application, we really need to know when anything goes wrong.  Just because it happened to go wrong when I did a query or an import operation does not mean that I don't care about the exception.

In the last forum post, the rationale for this behavior was:

> The argument for swallowing exceptions thrown during AddOnQuery (and
>   AddOnImport) was that "failing in the middle of a query is usually not
>   what the developer actually intended" because it was more likely to
>   occur due to a badly written event handler

Perhaps we aren't usual :-), but in our application, the event handler looks like this:

```
EntityManager.EntityChanged += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.Action == EntityAction.AddOnAttach ||
        e.Action == EntityAction.AddOnImport ||
        e.Action == EntityAction.AddOnQuery)
    {
        ((MyBaseClass) e.Entity).Initialize();
    }
};
```

Any exception thrown here are not going to be because of a badly written event handler.  Any exception that gets thrown here is because the entity got very confused while it was doing its one-time initialization logic.  And errors in that logic are *very* important to us.

I can understand that changing this universally might be dangerous and cause other application to start breaking.  But if there was some way that we could turn off this behavior or some other way to tell the Entity Manager not to swallow the exception, that would be very, very helpful.

Our previous workarounds are starting to fail as we look to use all our business logic in a Web Service where we can't just rely on error logging to handle this kind of thing.  We can't be returning a 'success' response to the caller just because DevForce swallowed a potentially fatal error.

We are on the latest version of DevForce (as of this writing: 2012 - 7.2.3).

Comment: We can revisit this.  If it turns out that exceptions are being swallowed due to some other DevForce misbehavior then I don't think we'll change this logic; but otherwise, this could be something we can address in the next release.

Comment: From what I can tell (take this with a grain of salt I suppose), the `EntityChanged` event isn't used by DevForce at all...so I don't think we'd have to worry about this change effecting standard DevForce behavior.

Comment: @KimJohnson When would you know whether this is going into the next release or not?  And perhaps even how you intended to fix it? I want to plan ahead a bit - if it turns out this won't be fixed in DevForce (or is fixed in a way that doesn't end up solving all our problems), I need to go back to the drawing board...

Comment: It's scheduled for the 7.2.4 release but has not been done yet.  We can probably get you an RC release early next week.

Comment: Well, this behavior has a long and byzantine history going back 5 years and the simplest approach, not bothering to catch and eat these exceptions, is probably not feasible.  Would making the OnEntityChanging/Changed methods on the EntityManager overrideable work for you?  If you'd still want to invoke your handlers from your overridden methods we could also add helper methods to do so.

Comment: The trouble I have with that option is that when I do things like an InvokeServerMethod call or I'm in an EntityServerSaveInterceptor call, all the entities are not in our custom/derived EM class - they are in a 'vanilla' EM.  For that reason, we've tried to avoid doing anything special in our custom entity manager class because we aren't always in control of the entity manager.  If there was an option where I could control this from outside the EM, that would be ideal - custom flag on the EM I turn on, a global setting in IdeaBladeConfig, custom delegate I provide the EM, ...

Comment: Okay, then how about a new flag on EntityManager.Options?

Comment: That would be perfect!

Comment: A 7.2.4 rc3 build with this change is now on the IdeaBlade ftp site.  This build also includes the ability to turn off or customize auto-retry, but I can explain how that works on your other thread if you have any questions.  As with the prior rc build, you'll need to clear your NuGet package source cache, since the package names have not changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 7.2.4 contains a flag, EntityManagerOptions.ThrowAllLoadExceptions, to control this behavior.  [Release notes.](http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/Documentation/release-notes#H7.2.4)

Comment: We've upgrade to 7.2.4 and this option is working perfectly for us!

Comment: We just found another place where exceptions are swallowed and it's causing us some major problems.  `EntityAspect.FirePropertyChanged` will swallow exceptions if `EntityManager.IsLoadingEntity` is true.  This seems like another place where `EntityManagerOptions.ThrowAllLoadExceptions` should overwrite that behavior.  From my understanding, this case is a 'load exception'.  Does that make sense?

Comment: You're right, any exceptions during load are swallowed here too.  OK, we should be able to fix this in the next release (7.2.7).

Comment: And if there are any other places where exceptions would be swallowed like this....it would be nice for them to get updated as well.  We've now come across two cases 'by accident'...I'm not sure how many other cases might be out there.

Comment: Nicest of all would be for this odd "swallowing" logic to have never been written at all, but you're right that fixes have been pretty haphazard as well.  We'll try to get everything this time.