# How to work with recursive/re-entrant Property Interceptors in DevForce

Tags: c#, devforce

Back in 2012, I ran into issues with Property Interceptors that were recursive (that is, they trigger the interceptor on the same property but of a difference instance).  It seems DevForce will ignore all but the first interceptor execution and that the behavior is expected and by design.  See [this forum post](http://forum.ideablade.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=3570&title=recursive-property-interceptors) for the full details.  I was able to redesign things in my application to work around that and all was well for a while.

Now I'm running into this same problem and I can't come up with anyway to work around it.  My new scenario that is breaking is a feature in our app where changes to one field can trigger changes to other fields and where this behavior is all dynamic and controlled by runtime configuration.  There are cases where we want a change of a property on one instance to change that same property on other instances (this is perhaps a simplification of our actual use case but it's hopefully close enough).  After debugging some bugs in that logic, I've realized that doesn't work because of this same recursive limitation.

I tried digging into the DevForce code to see if there is anyway we can work around this but I have been unsuccessful.  Is there anything I can do to get this to work?  I can understand the concerns mentioned in the forum post about how this could lead to infinite loops but in our case, I am fine with that kind of thing.  If I write code that would cause an infinite loop, I'd rather be greeted by a hung app that is easily debuggable rather than an app that silently goes on working even though things are subtly broken.

This reminds me of [this other issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24895137/385996) we ran into.  I can understand how DevForce might want to try to be friendly and try to mask programming errors by default, but I also like to be in control of that kind of decision.  From that other issue, an option was added so I could tell DevForce to have new behavior (`EntityManagerOptions.ThrowAllLoadExceptions`).  Perhaps a similiar option could be added for this?  I would love an `AllowReentrantPropertyInterceptors` option somewhere that I can flip to `true` (and would be `false` by default to avoid breaking backwards compatibility).

If a global option seemed too dangerous, I might be able to work with a public property on `PropertyInterceptor` like `ReentrancySupported` or something.  I'd likely end up having to just loop through every property in my model and set that to `true` though so a global option would be better.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with the original issue and will need to take a look at what's going on and why the limitation exists.

Comment: There is an explicit guard against recursion of a property interceptor action, although I don't know what the use case for this is/was.  When it detects recursion it actually invokes the "base" action for the getter/setter, which means looking at the "raw" entity value.  In the forum example you cite, the property setter for boss.FriendlyText has never been called, so its underlying raw value is still empty.  If possible, are you able to do something like "boss.FriendlyText = boss.FriendlyText" to ensure the setter is called?  I know it looks funny, but it does work around the issue.

Comment: I've worked around the original issue from the forum by basically eagerly populating FriendlyText without using interceptors at all.  But that doesn't really help me know where I have setter interceptors that I use to detect when properties change.  As it stands now, only the first setter interceptor fires and if that causes the same field to change on another instance, I don't get to know about it.

Comment: Also, in the original forum example, just ensuring the setter is called is not enough.  What if the friendly text included something like the current DateTime.  Just have the recursive call go to the 'base' action still wouldn't be good because then it's find the old value that had a DateTime for a while ago.

Comment: OK, the old example was for a property getter so I didn't focus on your need for property changes to cascade to other entities.  I suppose you've already looked at various property/entity change events or clever ways to queue triggered changes.  We can add a flag, probably on either the PropertyInterceptorManager or the PropertyInterceptor.

Comment: I tried every alternative I could think of but nothing seemed to work.  A flag on the `PropertyInterctorManager` would be amazing!

Comment: We'll include this in the next release, which should also include VS2017 (RC) support and a few minor fixes.  We don't have a date set, but I'd guess next month.

Comment: Great, thanks!  Any if it's possible to get an early beta build or anything, I'd be willing to take that as well.

Comment: Any update on when the new version might come out?  We aren't in a huge rush...I'm just being curious.  And fwiw, we aren't too worried about VS2017 support since I just found out 2017 won't support Silverlight :-(

Comment: It won't be this month.  We do need to support VS2017 so will wait until after its release on 3/7.  We'll aim to have a DevForce release later in March.

Comment: Just wanted to check on this as it's now April :-)

Comment: Release will be later this week.  I'll let you know when it's out.

Comment: DevForce 7.5 is now available.